# Need help finding a Chrome tab manager

Tags: chrome

I'm hating myself for not saving the name of this extension b/c I think it's really one of the best & under-rated tab manager/organizers out there.

There's a specific tab manager Chrome extension I have a lot of trouble remembering. Specifically, it has the following functions no other extensions (I believe) have:

1. the ability to move a tab into a new window
2. **the ability to move a tab into another existing window**

With this extension, on any Chrome tab you want, you press a specified keyboard shortcut, and a new **splash screen** (basically a custom new-tab) opens up. There, it asks you to specify which Chrome window you want the tab to be moved into (e.g. a new window, or a specified window labeled 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Does anyone know what extension I'm referring to? I forgot the name, and it's driving me insane to find it once again

Comment: This functionality doesn't seem to me to require an extension; one can simply drag/drop the tabs to create new windows or add them to existing windows. I do this all the time.

Comment: I was looking for an extension that allows you to use keyboard shortcuts to achieve that effect

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of [Cluster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cluster-window-tab-manage/aadahadfdmiibmdhfmpbeeebejmjnkef?hl=en).

Excerpted from its Chrome store page (emphasis mine):

> Features include undo removed tab or window, sorting windows tabs for better overview, showing the real tab URL when using the Great Suspender, launch the manager using keyboard shortcut, option to save or restore sessions from the manager or drop-down menu, search and filter for tabs by title or URL, **easily move tabs between windows**, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. It's called [Tabbo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabbo/hedbkonckghacebehjebpfknhdbobiko).